# How to compile C++20 CUDA program on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: cmake, cuda, c++20, ubuntu-20.04, nvcc

I am trying to build a program with some CUDA files using C++20 language standard on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) with `nvidia/cuda:12.1.0-devel-ubuntu20.04`:

```
The CUDA compiler identification is NVIDIA 12.1.105
```

First, I tried to add in CMakeLists.txt the lines

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

but it seems to have no effect. The compiler rejected even C++17 features, e.g.

```
warning #3033-D: inline variables are a C++17 feature
```

The second attempt was to add compiler flag directly:

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CUDA_FLAGS} --std c++20")
```

and I got

```
nvcc warning : The -std=c++20 flag is not supported with the configured host compiler. Flag will be ignored.
```

Which is very surprising considering that I tried both GCC 10 and Clang 11 as `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`.

The advice from the comments to write

```
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 20)
```

does not work unfortunately on Ubuntu 20 with its default Cmake 3.16:

```
CUDA_STANDARD is set to invalid value '20'
```

I would prefer manually passing command-option to the compiler to forcing Cmake update.

Comment: Your question is implicitly about cmake option passing. You only need  —std=c++20 to be passed to nvcc to compile c++20 code (within the limits of its support)

Comment: The variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is about standard use for compile **C++ sources**. For CUDA sources set `CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD` variable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, thanks, I did not try that. But it requires Cmake update in my case. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CMake documentation says that the first version to really support 20 for CUDA is 3.18.

> This property specifies the CUDA/C++ standard whose features are requested to build this target. For some compilers, this results in adding a flag such as -std=gnu++11 to the compile line.
> Supported values are:
>
> ...
>
> `20`
>
> *New in version 3.12.*
>
> CUDA C++20. While CMake 3.12 and later recognize `20` as a valid value, CMake 3.18 was the first version to include support for any
> compiler.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CUDA_STANDARD.html

Try updating your version of CMake.
For docker images, like the ones you are using, I sometimes have to download the binary and install it:

```
    - wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.27.0-rc3/cmake-3.27.0-rc3-linux-x86_64.sh --no-verbose
    - sh ./cmake-3.27.0-rc3-linux-x86_64.sh --skip-license --prefix=/usr
    - cmake --version
```

https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml?ref_type=heads#L402-403

Comment: Thanks. In addition to this I had to set `CMAKE_CUDA_HOST_COMPILER` to GCC 10 or Clang 11 since Ubuntu 20's default GCC 9 indeed does not not support command line option `-std=c++20`